# Which recommendation technique is preferred for content based system?

Tags: recommender-system

Lets say an application has to show documents which are relevant to users out of thousands of document in the dataset in content based system, which technique(set of algorithms) should be used ?

Problems to address:

1. The result should consider user's past preferences (history)
2. How to recommend any document when a new user comes (cold start problem)
3. A document can have 2 to 2000 words in it.

Things I explored:

1. cluster the whole dataset using LDA topic modelling
2. Use stop words | lemmatization | tf-idf | on all the docs and get the cosine similarity out of it
3. set a threshold on similarity and fetch all the similar docs

this link touches this aspect but still I couldn't get things clear 
[Neural Networks for Content Based Recommendation system](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/180530/neural-networks-for-content) based-recommendation-system.

Any kind of suggestion would be appreciable.

Comment: Did the methods you explored not work for you?

Comment: @Antimony , fortunately these steps did work for me but is there any other better way to address the above requirement ?